# Trouble with CGRectMake

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have been trying to create a grid on the iPhone of 16x16 images.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int xLocation = 0;

    for (int i=0; i <= 619; i++) {


        if (((i % 30) == 0) && i != 0) { //if at end of column (30th row), moves x over 16 px to next column
            xLocation += 16;
        }
        else {;}


    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake( xLocation, (16*i), 16, 16);
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
    [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Untitled-1.png"]];
    [image setOpaque:YES];

        NSLog(@"%d", xLocation);


    [self.view addSubview:image];
    [image release];
    }
```

The problem is the int xLocation. For some reason, CGRectMake uses 0 in the x-coordinate slot instead of xLocation. I say "instead of" because the NSLog below it reveals that the xLocation has the values that I want it to, so the assignment of the values is working fine. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xLocation is 0 for the first column and it is being increased for each column but the y coordinate is not being reset to 0 for each new column.  It just keeps increasing based on i.  So the columns from the second onward are just off screen at the right xLocation but a high y value.

Try changing the imageRect calculation to:

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake( xLocation, (16*(i % 30)), 16, 16);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had been focusing on xLocation, which wasn't actually the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Casting xLocation as an int in your NSLog will certainly work, but you could also use:

```
NSLog(@"imageRect %@", NSStringFromCGRect(imageRect));
```

There are a whole series of NSStringFromXXX helper functions that come in handy from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

%d doesn't present float's properly.  Use %f or convert xLocation to an int:

```
NSLog(@"%d", (int)xLocation);
```

You can also simplify your xLocation calculation readability by calculating it each time, something like

```
16 * (i / 30)
```

The overhead is minimal on modern processors.

Comment: `xLocation` is of type `int`.